# Basic Set Theory: Existence of Three Specific Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Do there exist sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$, $A\cap C = \emptyset$ and $(A\cap B)\setminus C = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. We argue by contradiction. Suppose instead that these sets really did exist.  Then since $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, we know that there exists some $x \in A \cap B$ so that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. There are exactly two cases to consider.

**Case 1:** Suppose that $x\in C$. Then since $x\in A$, we know that $x\in A\cap C$. But this contradicts the fact that $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

**Case 2:** Suppose that $x\notin C$. Then since $x \in A \cap B$, we know that $x\in (A \cap B) \setminus C$. But this contradicts the fact that $(A \cap B) \setminus C = \emptyset$.

In either case, we derived a contradiction. Thus, no such sets exist, as desired.

Comment: I like your because it used the $\overset{n}{\underset{i=0}{\large\wedge}}p_i \implies q$ method.

Comment: I like yours* because

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $(A \cap B) \setminus C = \emptyset$; then $A \cap B \subseteq C$. But $A \cap C = \emptyset$ gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: In order to have $(A\cap B)\setminus C=\varnothing$, you must have $A\cap B\subseteq C$. This in turn implies that  $(A\cap B)\cap C=A\cap B\ne\varnothing$. On the other hand, $(A\cap B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\cap B=\ldots$ what?